# Reporting tool for OLAP, *not* OLTP!

Tags: .net, reporting, olap-cube, star-schema, snowflake-schema

I'm looking for a control that I can put on top of an already existing OLAP star schema to allow the user to define their own "queries" and generate reports.  Right now I have some predefined reports built on top of the cubes, but I'd like to allow the user to define their own criteria based on the cubes that I've created.  I've found lots of products that will allow you to treat a transactional table like an OLAP cube, but nothing specifically for pre-existing cubes.

EDIT: Let me be clear, I know there are countless reporting tools out there that claim to report on OLAP cubes.  The problem is they all assume they are looking at transactional data and try to create their own cubes.  I have tables that contain tens, if not hundreds of millions of records.  Most tools crash when handling this much data, the others just run incredible slowly.  I don't want a tool that is targeting the business people.

I want a tool that understands what a star and snowflake schema is.  I want to be able to tell it what the fact tables are and what the dimension tables are, and then creates a UI on top of them.  This is an easier problem to solve for the tool vendor because I am spoon feeding them the cubes.  I want to rely on the fact that cubes are a standardized pattern and I want a tool that takes advantage of this fact.  I want a tool that targets developers and starts with the assumption that I actually know how to manage my data, it just needs to build pretty reports for me and not crumble under the weight of my data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well SSRS for SQL Server is designed to be used with cubes (we query our data warehouses with this all the time), but that is a vendor specific implementation and if you don't have SQL server you can't use it as it comes with SQL Server. You can write MDX queries and not just straight t-sql. I know you can reference other databases in queries, but I have never tried to reference a different vendors' tables becasue our data warehous in a SQL Server data warehouse.

Answer (score 1):

I've used various reporting tools, but by far the most familiar to the end users is MS Excel Pivot Tables. Please follow [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP101672991033.aspx) to further information.

Comment: This will not scale 64,000 rows max for an EXCEL spreadsheet!

Comment: I agree, but I'm sticking to a 80/20 principle, so if you have the need to manage HUGE cubes with terabytes of data and a lot dimensions and calculated measures, obviously you must purchase a dedicated tool, like COGNOS. But, like everything, sometimes a missile is not the best tool to kill a butterfly.

Comment: 64,000 row limit is for Excel 2003/xp or earlier

If you were embedding, it would be more likely that you'd use Office Web Components [OWC]

Answer (score 1):

If you want a full enterprise-level software, you're looking for a tool like the [Cognos](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/cognos/products/cognos-8-business-intelligence/)(IBM) reporting suite. Their tools have a single query framework for reporting against both relational and OLAP sources, depending on how you model it. That means you can do multidimensional reporting against SQL server and MSAS with the same tool if it's modeled properly. They support their own cubes, TM1, ORacle, Microsoft, SAPBW, etc... There's an sdk you can use to write your own front-end tool as well. Not cheap, but nothing enterprise is.

Competitors in this field (I haven't used) are [Business Objects](http://www.sap.com/solutions/sapbusinessobjects/index.epx)(SAP) and [Hyperion](http://www.oracle.com/hyperion/index.html)(Oracle). And maybe [JasperSoft](http://www.jaspersoft.com/) (open source).

Also check out the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110032/star-schema-design). He mentions BO and a Microsoft solution.

Answer (score 0):

Stefan, if your end-goal is for reporting I would suggest a tool like Tableau. It is very simply to learn for the average user and it allows them to make reports on the fly using the interface or type custom queries against the database. If you are looking for something more advanced I would suggest a product like CockPit (I know...) developed by a German based company that is also really neat and starting to take off.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think those tools are what I'm looking for.  Both look like all the other reporting tools that I've seen that assume they are starting with an OLTP schema.  Please see my updates to the question and correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Dundas](http://www.dundas.com/Components/Products/Chart/NET/OLAP/index.aspx) solution which allows end users to create their own reports based on dimensions and measures created in the cube.

Answer (score 0):

Are you after something like [Mondrian](http://mondrian.pentaho.org/)? We used it on a previous project, and I seem to recall its OLAP reporting was pretty good. Can't remember if it had a gui, though; that wasn't my area. I only ever messed with the config files...

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use SSRS where user can build reports just browsing the cube or u can write custom mdx queries using the OLAP advantage.
You can use SQL Server Report Builder 
And last not least Microsoft Excel 2007 has good capability of browsing a cube 
You can even expose your cube in SharePoint via Microsoft excel services 2007

Answer (score 0):

I hold my hands up and freely-admit that I'm not an expert in this domain, but you could have a look at [InfoBright](http://www.infobright.com/).  I understand it will still go off and index your existing data (I'm not sure if it forms its own cubes), but I'm led to believe it can handle massive amounts of data quickly.

There's a community edition and a commercial edition too.  I've never used the software, but from what I've read about it before, it seems impressive.

Answer (score 0):

You could give [Web Pivot Table](http://webpivottable.com) a try and it is a web based reporting tool which connect to both CSV files and OLAP cubes just like excel pivot table. Here is [demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo) and [documents](http://webpivottable.com/documents).

You can connect to multiple source data (for example, multiple OLAP cubes), create multiple pivot tables and pivot charts and then create multiple reports based on any combination of these pivot tables and pivot charts.